# How to parametrize UUID in upload XML-attachment in Jmeter?

Tags: soap, jmeter, uuid

I need to make stress test with method POST (SOAP API). I tried to use function `${_UUID}` to make UUID like `abec119d-2d8e-4705-a994-f7c326967bnn` and send XML code in body data of HTTP request, but it fails with response

> 500 (Invalid Security Header)

So, my question is - is it possible, to randomize UUID in uploading XML file or how can I make it?

Answer (score 1):

`Invalid Security Header` message indicates that the contents of your [`wsse:Security` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WS-Security) is malformed.

Without seeing the header itself it's hard to say what's wrong exactly, most probably you're sending a hard-coded timestamp which in the past hence server doesn't accept it. Also it could be that the signature is required and again your hard-coded signature is not accepted.

I would recommend installing [**WS Security for SOAP**](https://github.com/tilln/jmeter-wssecurity) plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]

and once you perform the necessary configuration it should generate the "good" header so your SOAP request will be accepted.